Почему ругается на тип данных в списке?
data = []
dig = float(input("введи число(пустая строка для окончания ввода): "))
while dig != "":
    data.append(dig)
    dig = float(input("введи число(пустая строка для окончания ввода): "))
print(data)
average_value = sum(data) / len(data)
print(average_value)

Ошибка

ValueError: could not convert string to float


А где тут у списка указан тип данных? Может так попробовать data: list[float] = []. Или я вообще вопроса не понял. Ошибка то где конкретно и с чем связана?

Ругается на то что в списке строчный тип данных  - ValueError: could not convert string to float: '', если закоментить всю ерунду с циклом while и конкретно написать data = [1, 2, 3, 4]  то среднее заначение считается коректно

@He110_LSD ну у тебя вообще не понятно, что ты намудрил. С одной стороны dig = float, с другой стороны ты его проверяешь как строку dig != ""

сперва надо проверить что вводит пользователь, и если это не пустая строка, тогда уже приводить к float, поэтому и ругается что пустая строка вызывает ошибку ValueError: could not convert string to float

ну так все верно, ошибка из-за того, что вы пытаетесь привести пустое значение к float

@AlexanderLonberg ну а как тогда лучше сделать окончание ввода? Поменял на while dig != 0: и заработало

Программа предусматривает завершение при пустой строке (нажатии Enter) - её невозможно привести к типу float. Поэтому нужно отдельно проверять строку (не пустая ли) и уже потом приводить к float.
Если строка пустая, то в булевых выражениях она будет интерпретирована как False, что прервет цикл while. В Python 3.8 появился моржовый оператор :=, который позволяет присвоить значение переменной и использовать это значение в выражении одновременно. В совокупности получаем более короткий код:
data = []
while dig := input("Введи число (пустая строка для окончания ввода): "):
    data.append(float(dig))
print(data)


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Среднее арифметическое элементов списка
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

import os as os
import decimal as decimal

print("-" * 50 + "\nСреднее арифметическое элементов списка:\n" + "-" * 50)

while True:

    ok = True

    lst_numbers = input("\nУкажите перечень чисел, разделённых пробелами: ").strip().replace(",", ".").split()
    if not lst_numbers:
        print("Перечень чисел не задан! Попробуйте ещё раз...")
        ok = False
    else:
        try:
            lst_result = list(map(lambda i: decimal.Decimal(i), lst_numbers))
        except:
            print("Введено ошибочное значение числа! Попробуйте ещё раз...")
            ok = False

    if ok:
        break

print("\nЭлементы списка:", lst_numbers)
print("Среднее арифметическое элементов списка:", decimal.Decimal(sum(lst_result) / len(lst_result)))

print("\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul")

